# Encryption in GSM Voice communication

Tags: encryption, gsm

Is there end-to-end voice encryption in GSM ?
If not, is voice communication between mobile handset and
mobile base station, at least encrypted ?
What keys are used there and which alogrithms ? any idea?

Comment: this question is interesting as was the discussion, but StackOverflow is for programming-related questions only. The uber-users seem to define this pretty narrowly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there end-to-end voice encryption in GSM ?

No.

> If not, is voice communication between mobile handset and mobile base station, at least encrypted ?

Yes. Read [this](http://reflextor.com/trac/a51/wiki/A5/1Basics).

> What keys are used there and which alogrithms ?

A3, A5 and A8 (mostly COMP128).

For more references, read [this](http://reflextor.com/trac/a51) and [this](http://www.gsmworld.com/using/algorithms/).

Comment: I don't think this is the case.  If there was end-to-end encryption, the authorities couldn't wiretap you.  But they can.  Base station to handset encryption, yes.  Handset-to-handset; no.

Comment: The encryption in GSM is not end-to-end; it is between the handset and the base station only.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my answer. It's not end-to-end, really, only between handset and BTS.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, the encryption algorithms are different for 3G and 2G - not sure if you meant to be 2G specific in your question.

Again, for 3G the encryption is between the handset and the base station (or RNC - Radio Network Controller in 3G).

Note also that both 2G and 3G encryption have reportedly been cracked now:

http://www.engadget.com/2010/01/15/3g-gsm-encryption-cracked-in-less-than-two-hours/

Answer (score 0):

```
Is there end-to-end voice encryption in GSM ?
```

No

However you can use [secure voice](http://www.secure-voice.com/home.html) on certain phones